# program control over azure vm start/stop

Tags: c#, azure

I would like my program to be able to start and stop an azure vm. I managed to write a powershell script that starts and stops the VM but I would like to do it from my C# directly (that is, without calling the powershell script. I did not manage to find the way to do this translation and I will appreciate the help.

Here is the PowerShell script
    function stopvm($resourcegroup,$vmname) 
    { 
         Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroup $resourcegroup -Name $vmname 
    }

```
function startvm($resourcegroup,$vmname) 
{ 
    Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroup $resourcegroup -Name $vmname 
} 

################################################################ 
# Please Change These Variables to Suit Your Environment 
# 


 $subscriptionname = "Subscription Name"
 $resourcegroup = "Resource Group Name" 
 $vmname = "VM name"

 ################################################################ 

 Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionName $subscriptionname
 write-host "Choose the options to Start and Stop your Azure VMS" 
    write-host "1. Start VM" 
    write-host "2. Stop VM" 
 $answer = read-host "Please Select Your Choice" 

 Switch($answer) 
 { 
    1{ StartVM $resourcegroup $vmname} 
    2{ StopVM $resourcegroup $vmname} 
 }
```

The main obstacle is to find the C# translation of Login-AzureRm

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you can use to start your VM:

```
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("[OAUTH2 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT]");

        UserCredential userCred = new UserCredential("[CO-ADMINISTRATOR E-MAIL]", "[CO-ADMINISTRATOR PASSWORD]");

        AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", "[APPLICATION CLIENT ID]", userCred).Result;

        TokenCloudCredentials credentials = new TokenCloudCredentials("[SUBSCRIPTION ID]", result.AccessToken);

        using (ComputeManagementClient computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials))
        {
            computeClient.VirtualMachines.Start("[CLOUD SERVICE NAME]", "[DEPLOYMENT NAME]", "[VM NAME]");
        }
```

**EDIT:**

This requires you to install the following NuGet packages:

[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute/)

[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)

Comment: Would be nice if you could also share the Nuget package to install where these APIs live

Comment: @FrankQ. - Good point, added two that are required. One for authentication with AAD and the other one with service management SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately it is not working yet. I would like it to prompt for the email and password (especially in my org where we use 2 forms of authentication I need it to prompt similar experience to the one you have in visual studio when you login to TFS). Currently I get an error message: "AADSTS50079: Strong authentication enrollment (proof-up) is required." and it never prompts for credentials.

Comment: deprecated packages :(